# Вопрос по void Update и инкременту переменной

Tags: c#

У меня есть  переменная `public Int Counter=0;`
и в методе Update есть динамическое условие при котором выполняется условие  `if (Obj.IntersectsWith(Obj1))` я хочу вести учет выполнения условия  и добавляю в блок if код инкремент `Counter++;` но он не увеличивает значение `public Int Counter=0;` хотя все условия выполняются .А если `Counter++;` добавить просто в метод Update   то счетчик считает кол. выполнения Update .

Подскажите почему так ? 
Прочитал [Инкремент, декремент и побочные эффекты](https://ravesli.com/urok-40-inkrement-dekrement-pobochnye-effekty/) но без результата.

Comment: Вангую, что у Counter надо модификатор static ещё написать. Покажите весь код, подозреваю, что вы увеличиваете счётчик у одного экземпляра класса, а потом смотрите его в другом экземпляре. А ведь у каждого экземпляра - свой счётчик. Вот если указать static, то будет один счётчик на все экземпляры.

Comment: Ваша правда при static Int Counter=0; все заработало как надо. Огромное спасибо .